# Predict the values in Test.csv files using the developed ML model

Tags: python

```
array = [[]]

for i in range(len(test_data)):

  d = np.array(test_data.loc[i,test_data.columns],ndmin=2)

  value = loaded_model.predict(d)

  array.append(value)
```

My goal is to predict values in the test.csv files by using the devoloped model. I tried the above code which does not seem to be working. Getting the value error.

Comment: can you add what error is showing up?

Comment: [see if this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577999/feature-names-mismach-in-xgboost-despite-having-same-columns)

Comment: Got it. Thanks Following is the colab file link which I worked on:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f3xX4_zj6nrsAsqIriITLKe2_RphTtOP?usp=sharing

Comment: I am able to fix the error. Thank you so much @noober